# missing } after property list error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am encountering the above mentioned error, I wonder why it is popping up. All my curly brackets are correct as far as I see. Given below is the code segment:

```
var mapped = data.map(d => {

    return {
        date: d.date;
        value: d.count;
    }
});
```

The console is pointing to this line:

```
date: d.date;
```

I wonder why this is popping up. Any help is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrectly used semicolon within objects.

The properties within an object should be separated using commas.

```js
var data = [];

var mapped = data.map(d => {

    return {
        date: d.date, // here you used `;` instead of comma 
        value: d.count
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah.. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Every objects can contains multiple attributes/properties and each must be separated with `,`.
Please adopt the following code and you'll be good to go.

```
var mapped = data.map(d => {
    return {
        date: d.date,
        value: d.count
    }
});
```